# How to construct this turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines, automata

How can we construct TMs such that it accepts(Give description only):

> a + b = c
>
> a . b = c

Input is of the form a#b#c.

a,b and c belongs to {0,1}* and are positive binary unsigned integers.

***I know that we can construct TMs if the input has unary representation but how to solve if it has binary representation?***

Comment: Didi you try to construct it yourself? Where did you got stuck? As a hint, first try to construct an algorithm that adds (multiplies) two numbers and write it as a pseudocode. Then you could convert it to the TM instructions. Warning: writing the whole TM, especially for multiplication, is quite boring work.

Comment: I was trying to solve it using 3-tape TM. It works in 3 phases.. first it copies b and c onto tapes 2 and 3 and then adds a and b and store it in tape 1/2 and then match. The problem is I got stuck with binary addition step. How do I write an algo?

Comment: Do you how to add two binary numbers using the grade school addition algorithm ? If yes, then first construct a TM which only adds two numbers.